# What is the opposite of widow? If A is the widow of B, then B is the ____ of A?

Tags: antonyms

When one of a married couple dies, there's a word (widow or widower) to refer to the survivor, but there seems to be no word to refer to the deceased.

My wife was a widow when I met her.  How should I refer to her last husband?  Saying "ex-husband" implies they are divorced.  Saying "dead ex-husband" sounds gruesome, and implies that perhaps they were divorced when he died.

Comment: The dead guy is her 'late husband'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context you would use the word 'late'.

> The late Elvis Presley...
>
> Mrs Smith's late husband used to...

This means the person is deceased.

However, it's normally used when the person hasn't remarried. So *my wife's late husband* could be confusing, since if her husband's dead who are you?!

You *could* still use this phrase but for clarity I would recommend either

> my wife's late former husband

or

> my wife's late first husband

(Note the adjective order. *Former late husband* sounds like he's no longer dead and *first late husband* sounds like she's got more than one dead husband.)

*Ex-husband* is used so often as a phrase that I think if you said *late ex-husband* people would think they were divorced before he died. For this reason, *late first husband* might be better than *late former husband*. I think semantically *late first husband* is better as well, because he didn't technically **stop** being her husband when he died (otherwise the phrase *late husband* wouldn't be used to begin with).

Comment: Thanks for the well-thought out answer.  I think technically he did stop being her husband when he died.  There really should be a word for this.

Comment: I think phrases like *late husband* indicate that he didn't (compare *dead husband* with *dead ex-husband*), but it's definitely a confusing area.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously saying "dead husband" would be a bit grim, but saying "late husband" seems to be acceptable and generally implied deceased as opposed to divorced.

This is the case in the UK